# Can I convert row value contains of stringified array to array in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a row which the value is the string of array. I need to convert it to the array.

[image]

I tried to convert it by strip the quote using `SUBSTR` function.

```
WITH k AS (SELECT 1 as id, (SELECT after.ClientIds   
FROM `kube-playground.events.login_v2_users`) AS c)

Select id, ARRAY(SELECT * FROM UNNEST(SPLIT(SUBSTR(c, 2 , LENGTH(c) - 2)))) AS x from k
```

It is failed because Scalar subquery produced more than one element. Any tips or ideas for this problem? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

You can simply use [JSON_EXTRACT_ARRAY](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/json_functions#json_extract_array) as in below example

```
#standardSQL
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT_ARRAY(ClientIds)
FROM `kube-playground.events.login_v2_users`
```

You can test it as in below

```
#standardSQL
WITH `kube-playground.events.login_v2_users` AS (
  SELECT '[{"time":"asd", "id":"qwe"},{"time":"asd2", "id":"qwe2"},{"time":"asd3", "id":"qwe3"}]' ClientIds UNION ALL
  SELECT '[{"time":"aseft", "id":"sdf"},{"time":"aseft2", "id":"sdf2"}]'
)
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT_ARRAY(ClientIds)
FROM `kube-playground.events.login_v2_users`
```

with result

```
Row f0_  
1   {"time":"asd","id":"qwe"}    
    {"time":"asd2","id":"qwe2"}  
    {"time":"asd3","id":"qwe3"}  
2   {"time":"aseft","id":"sdf"}  
    {"time":"aseft2","id":"sdf2"}
```